# How to Deal with Java JNI Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am facing inconsistent behavior on Java JNI functions.  The same code behaviors differently in different environment.  I need your help.

I used Java JNI and C++ created a one function DLL file.  That function takes a string as the only parameter and read that string out.  I created a test program to test the DLL.  In the test program there is a JNI class, CppWrapper, to load the DLL and call the native function inside the DLL.  The test was successful.
Below is the JNI class

```
public class CppWrapper {       
    static{
        String jvmBits = System.getProperty("os.arch");
        if(jvmBits.equals("x86")){
            System.loadLibrary("voice32");
            System.out.println(“CppWrapper voice32 loaded”);    
        }else{
            System.loadLibrary("voice64");
            System.out.println(“CppWrapper voice64 loaded”);
        }    
    }   
    native public static int speak(String str);      
}
```

Calling the native method in the JNI class:

```
String line = toSpeakTextArea.getText();
CppWrapper.speak(line);
```

I copied the whole JNI class to the application I am working on and the exact code caused “java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError”.   The DLL file is loaded but the function inside the DLL cannot be found.  Changing name of the JNI class in the test program caused the same error.  Taking the original test program to other PC fails the same way.

I made the test program into a jar file and use it as dependency for my application and it worked.

Now the situation is that the exactly JNI related code can only work on a particular PC under particular class name. Otherwise it will fail.  How you can fix this problem?

I use Netbeans 8.01, JDK1.7.0-67, and JRE1.7.0-67.  All projects are Maven projects.

Below Error Message is from running the original test program on a different PC.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mycompany.speechuserxp.CppWrapper.speak(Ljava/lang/String;)I
at com.mycompany.speechuserxp.CppWrapper.speak(Native Method)
at com.mycompany.speechuserxp.SpeechUserXP.speakButtonActionPerformed(SpeechUserXP.java:143)
at com.mycompany.speechuserxp.SpeechUserXP.access$100(SpeechUserXP.java:15)
at com.mycompany.speechuserxp.SpeechUserXP$2.actionPerformed(SpeechUserXP.java:97)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `System.load()` with an absolute path name instead of `System.loadLibrary()`?

Comment: @SamuelAudet I tried. I got a error message saying "c:/windows/system32/voice32.dll is not found on library.path"